# $S_5$ does not act transitively on $\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have seen a statement: let $S_n$ act transitively on a set with $m$ elements. Then, $m\leq 2$ or $n \leq m$. I was able to prove it, so I believe it. However, I find this strikingly unintuitive. For instance, $S_5$ contains $S_3$, which acts transitively on $\{1,2,3\}$, so shouldn't $S_5$ also act transitively? Where is the gap in my logic here?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Can someone give me an example of a non-trivial action of $S_5$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ that is not transitive?

Comment: Can't really tell where your error is if you don't show your argument.

Comment: If $S_5$ acts transitively on $\{1,2,3\}$ it has a subgroup of index $3$. The transitive action on the cosets induces a non-trivial homomorphism $S_5 \to S_3$. This is a contradiction as the kernel can only be $A_5$ or $S_5$.

Comment: But by the argument in my question $S_5$ acts transitively on $\{1,2,3\}$, so I guess I've shown mathematics is inconsistent. But I don't want mathematics to be inconsistent so someone please prove me wrong.

Comment: (G acts on X) **and**  (a subgroup H acts transitively on X) $\Longrightarrow $ G acts transitively on X

Comment: @user302540: The problem is that your subgroup of index $3$ [does not exist](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89040/no-subgroup-of-s-5-with-order-40). (If such a subgroup would exist your reasoning would be right.)

Comment: (new edited question:) If $\sigma$ is even permutation, define $\sigma.i=i$ for $i=1,2,3$, and if $\sigma$ is odd, define $\sigma.1=2$, $\sigma.2=1$ and $\sigma.3=3$

Comment: The problem is that $S_5$ will not act in the natural way on $\{1,2,3\}$, as the image of $3$ under $(3,4)$ is not in the set,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to extend the acton of $S_3$ on $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to an action of $S_5$ on $\{1, 2, 3\}$, i.e. you would need to extend the identity $\mathrm{id} \colon S_3 \to S_3$ to a group epimorphism $p \colon S_5 \to S_3$. This is not possible.

More generally, there exists *no* group epimorphism $p \colon S_n \to S_m$ if $n \geq 5$ and $n \neq m > 2$ because then [$A_n$ is the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$](http://planetmath.org/normalsubgroupsofthesymmetricgroups). We would then have $\ker p = \{1\}$, and contradicting $n \neq m$, or $\ker p = A_n$, contradicting $m \neq 2$, or $\ker p = S_n$, contradicting $m \neq 1$.

PS: As we can see from this argument there are precisely four actions of $S_5$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, classified by the group homomorphisms $p \colon S_5 \to S_3$. The case $\ker p = S_5$ corresponds to the trivial action. If $\ker p = A_5$ then $\mathrm{im} \ p \cong S_2$, so we have three such actions, corresponding to the three transpositions of $S_5$: So we fix any of the three elements and let $S_5$ swap the other two where $A_5$ does nothing.

Comment: I already understood one can't extend the action but I'm still confused. Can you can give me an action of $S_5$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ that is not transitive?

Answer (score 1):

Standard argument (above) is through *group action and homomorphism*. Here is a little different:

suppose $S_5$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}$ transitively. Then $|S_5|=|\mathrm{Orbit}(i)|.|\mathrm{Stab}(i)|=3.|\mathrm{Stab}(i)|$, hence $\mathrm{Stab}(i)$ is subgroup of index $3$ in $S_5$, so its order is $40$. In group of order $40$, Sylow-$5$ subgroup is normal, i.e. normalizer of Sylow-$5$ subgroup in $S_5$ contains $\mathrm{Stab}(i)$. So index of normalizer in $S_5$ of Sylow-$5$ subgroup is $\leq 3$, i.e. number of Sylow-$5$ subgroups in $S_5$ is $\leq 3$, contradiction (it is $6$).